# How to search highlighted word immediately via F3 without first pressing CTRL-F?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, on Windows, is there a setting (I looked but couldn't find) that will let me just press F3 to search the current highlighted word without first having to press CTRL-F ?

It's incredibly convenient to just double-click a word then F3 to search it.  Other editors (like UltraEdit) do this; hoping VS Code has this ability. Perhaps an extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Just after I wrote this, the `multi-command` extension was updated!  For a simple macro like this, you no longer need to have the `settings.json` entry mentioned below.  This keybinding is enough:

```
  {
    "key": "F3",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
      "sequence": [
        "actions.find",
        "editor.action.nextMatchFindAction"
      ]
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  }
```

---

Previous answer I'll probably delete shortly (as the extension was updated shortly after I wrote the following)::

I don't think there is a direct way to do that but you could make a macro that seems to work well.  Using [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command):

In `settings.json`:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [

  {
    "command": "multiCommand.findNext",
    "sequence": [
      "actions.find",
      "editor.action.nextMatchFindAction"
    ]
  }
}
```

and a keybinding (in keybindings.json) to trigger that:

```
{
  "key": "F3",               // whatever keybinding you wish
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "command": "multiCommand.findNext"
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

You don't need to double-click the word first, just have the cursor in it.  If you want to **require** that the word be selected, use this `when` context instead:

`"when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"`

It does need to use your Find widget so it will replace whatever value may have been in it before.

Demo not requiring a selection, just current word:

[image: find next macro demo]

It is actually a nice little functionality boost - I think I will start to use this (with a keybinding where I don't have to hit a function key though).